# Referral for new members

Tags: discussion

Like DropBox gives a space increase for the referrer and referee, is there any plans to add a referal link for a small rep boost? If someone signs up and gets at least 10 rep then the referrer gets 5 or something like that. Once they refer 5 users they could have a badge or similar.

I'm not sure how this would work with OpenID and I hate people who whore DropBox links, although it's a small idea (and I've not managed to find if it's been mentoined before).

Comment: The only thing you would get is a badge like [Announcer](http://superuser.com/badges/64/announcer) or [Promoter](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/207/promoter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that we will ever see this coming to the StackExchange community, as the purpose of the StackExchange is to encourage a Question/Answer atmosphere.  This is not a blog in that we invite people to just read, but rather to give input.  Sure there is a sense of looking for answers to your question, that may have already been answered here, but the ultimate goal is for a community driven questioning and answering.

Comment: Thanks for a quick, honest, fair response.

Comment: @tombull89 you're actually lucky that I was on meta at the time... that's why it was so quick. These aren't always answered in a timely fashion.